# Where to add the period for htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following in my htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_-]+)$ profile.php?uid=$1
```

The problem is that a period will break the page, for example: www.mydomain.com/john.smith

How can I allow the period?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your situation/context, you can either check for, and exclude, requests for `profile.php`, or check if the request is for an existing file or directory:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/profile\.php
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_.-]+)$ profile.php?uid=$1
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_.-]+)$ profile.php?uid=$1
```

Comment: I tried your first solution, and my site wouldn't load anymore. I tried the second, but `www.mydomain.com/john.smith` still didn't work.

Comment: @Phil They both work perfectly fine for me in a blank htaccess file on a vanilla apache 2.2: Both [First](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nP1cu.png) and [Second](http://i.stack.imgur.com/80vvL.png)

Comment: I'm not sure why the first one didn't work for me, but the second one is working now, so thanks! could I ask you for a short explanation of the solution, as I'm trying to learn as much as I can about the topic. Thanks!

Comment: @Phil The reason why you were getting a 500 error is because if you match a grouping that includes dots `.`, it matches `profile.php` because the rewrite engine keeps looping, and that'll cause an infinite loop. The conditions prevent that from happening.

Comment: 2nd version worked for me too - just wanted to say thanks on a 10 year old answer!